# Drag&drop items limited

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

is it possible to put limit to items for dragging? For example; only 3 items may dropped each boxes etc.

**My Javascript codes:**

```
$("#DraggItems  .draggable-item").draggable({ helper: "clone", cursor: "drop-hover"});

$("#DraggItems").droppable({
     drop:function(event, ui) {
            hoverClass: "drop-hover",
            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));

     } 
});    

$("div.draggable-list").droppable({
     drop:function(event, ui) {
            hoverClass: "drop-hover",
            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));

     } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to put a limit to item for dragging.

```
 if($this.find('.drag').length >= 3){               
    ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    return;
 }
```

See this fiddle in action: http://jsfiddle.net/qqqm6/568/

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much @Sanyami

Comment: @Baris remember to mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark :-)